# How to make "local" the label in a 8086 procedure?

Tags: local, label, x86-16, procedures

The problem is that some (many) labels have the same name, in particular: there are many procedures and each works properly if run "isolated" from the others. In fact, the labels used in different procedures have all the same common names such as "skip", "cycle", and so on.

I know that in the macros could be used the directive `LOCAL <label1>, <label2>, ...`. But this directive doesn't work into a procedure.

Changing each label is very boring, but not impossible to do, the real problem is that if I want to avoid the duplicates I have to use strange names o I have to remember when I used "skip23" instead "skip22". All this is making me crazy.

Comment: Depends on the assembler.

Comment: I am using both MASM and emu8086, can this help you?

Comment: Labels in newer MASM (>=6) are local between `PROC` and `ENDP`. Older MASM need additionally a langtype in the .model directive, e.g. `.model small, C`. Emu8086 has no local "procedure"-labels. You could tricky work with macros, but I advise against it.